# SwiftUI selectable Text on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

How would one display text in swiftUI that can be selected? As in Terminal app on macOS for example?

`Text("This is some text")` displays text but it is not selectable.

I am new to GUI development on Mac. Should I be using some other View?

Comment: **NOT** fixed in GM.

Comment: Found a similar issue. In terms of GUI development for mac, if you are serious about the app you're making I still suggest going back to regular appkit and using XIBs or maybe storyboards. Even programmatic UI like you'd do on iOS is a bit horrendous on appkit

Answer (score 0):

You can use it since macOS12 and iOS 15 as:

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .textSelection(.enabled)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Button to Wrap the Text or use the Button directly.

```
Button("This is some text") {
   print("do something here")
}
```